# map an XML string into HTML page with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, dom, dictionary

I have a XML string stored as a javascript string.

```
<script src="jquery.mobile/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

testXML="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\n\
<DataGroup>\n\
    <RequestHdr>\n\
        <XORN>98765</XORN>\n\
        <STDE>20110101</STDE>\n\
        <ARTE>20110102</ARTE>\n\
    </RequestHdr>\n\
</DataGroup>";

$(document).ready(function()
{

});

</script>
```

and I want to map this directly into an HTML fragment that looks like this.

```
<input type="text" name="XORN" id="preXord" value=""  />
<input type="text" name="STDE" id="preTrav" value="" />
<input type="text" name="ARTE" id="preArr"  value=""  />
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are just wanting the values in xorn, stde, and arte (xml) to be used in the input values

you can do

```
var $xml = $.parseXML( testXML );
$('#preXord').val($xml.find('XORN').text());
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var xml="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>\n\
<DataGroup><RequestHdr><XORN>98765</XORN><STDE>20110101</STDE><ARTE>20110102</ARTE></RequestHdr></DataGroup>";


    xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );



$("#preXord").val($xml.find("XORN").text());
$("#preTrav").val($xml.find("STDE").text());
$("#preArr").val($xml.find("ARTE").text());
```

here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wBJyQ/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at jQuery [parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) that will help you in this case and also make you understand how it works.